Filament widgets grid and stats overview
I'm using filament dashboard and i'm trying to use some stats overview widgets. the problem is the styling as you can see. I created a custom dashboard page to put this global filter and i gave the main page this column grid
    public function getColumns(): int | string | array
{
    return [
        'sm' => 1,
        'md' => 2,
        'xl' => 3,
    ];}

and i gave each one of the state overview widgets this line of code
    protected int | string | array $columnSpan = '1';

The inspector in browser shows that each on of them is taking it's place but the content is not. I tried to type css in the inspector when i type grid-column: span 4;  it become normal then return back to this. Is there's a way to fix this or how to type custom css in filament to solve this.

I searched alot to solve this problem but i didn't find a solution also i tried to change the col span in each one of them but it only shows correctly when it's taking the whole row but i need to put in each row 3 widgets for the design. I've also tried to use a custom blade file for the dashboard page but I couldn't handle it with the filter I've on my widgets. is there's a solution without creating everything from scrath?
here is an example for my stats overview widget code
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Widgets;

use Filament\Widgets\StatsOverviewWidget as BaseWidget;
use Filament\Widgets\StatsOverviewWidget\Stat;
use App\Models\Order;
use Filament\Widgets\Concerns\InteractsWithPageFilters;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Filament\Widgets\StatsOverviewWidget\Card;



class OrderDeliveredWidget extends BaseWidget
{
    use InteractsWithPageFilters;

    protected int | string | array $columnSpan = '1';

    protected function getStats(): array
    {
        $query = Order::query();
        
        if ($this->filters['Date']) {
            $query->where('created_at', '>=', $this->getFilterDate($this->filters['Date']));
        }

        $currentCount = $query->where('status', 'delivered')->count();
        
        // Get the count for the previous period
        $previousPeriodStart = $this->getPreviousPeriodStart($this->filters['Date']);
    $previousCount = Order::where('status', 'delivered')
        ->where('created_at', '>=', $previousPeriodStart)
        ->where('created_at', '<', $this->getFilterDate($this->filters['Date']))
        ->count();

        $percentageChange = $this->calculatePercentageChange($previousCount, $currentCount);
        $description = $this->getDescription($percentageChange);
        $icon = $this->getDescriptionIcon($percentageChange);
        $color = $this->getColor($percentageChange);

        return [
            Stat::make('Delivered Orders', $currentCount)
                ->description($description)
                ->descriptionIcon($icon)
                ->color($color),
            // Add more Stat::make() calls for other metrics
        ];
    }

    private function getFilterDate(?string $filter): Carbon
{
    return match($filter) {
        'today' => now()->startOfDay(),
        'week' => now()->startOfWeek(),
        'month' => now()->startOfMonth(),
        'year' => now()->startOfYear(),
        default => Carbon::createFromTimestamp(0),
    };
}

    protected function getFilters(): ?array
    {
        return [
            'today' => 'Today',
            'week' => 'This week',
            'month' => 'This month',
            'year' => 'This year',
        ];
    }

    private function calculatePercentageChange($oldValue, $newValue): float
    {
        if ($oldValue == 0) {
            return $newValue > 0 ? 100 : 0;
        }
        return (($newValue - $oldValue) / $oldValue) * 100;
    }

    private function getDescription(float $percentageChange): string
    {
        $formattedChange = number_format(abs($percentageChange), 1);
        $direction = $percentageChange >= 0 ? 'increase' : 'decrease';
        return "{$formattedChange}% {$direction}";
    }

    private function getDescriptionIcon(float $percentageChange): string
    {
        return $percentageChange >= 0 
            ? 'heroicon-m-arrow-trending-up'
            : 'heroicon-m-arrow-trending-down';
    }

    private function getColor(float $percentageChange): string
    {
        if ($percentageChange > 10) {
            return 'success';
        } elseif ($percentageChange < -10) {
            return 'danger';
        } else {
            return 'warning';
        }
    }

    private function getPreviousPeriodStart(?string $filter): Carbon
{
    return match($filter) {
        'today' => now()->subDay()->startOfDay(),
        'week' => now()->subWeek()->startOfWeek(),
        'month' => now()->subMonth()->startOfMonth(),
        'year' => now()->subYear()->startOfYear(),
        default => Carbon::createFromTimestamp(0),
    };
}
}


and thats the filter on dashboard file
public function filtersForm(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Section::make()
                    ->schema([
                        Select::make('Date')
                            ->options([
                                "all" => "All Time",
                                'today' => "Today",
                                "week" => "Week",
                                "month" => "Month",
                                "year" => "Year"
                            ])
                            ->default('all'),
                    ])
                    ->columns(1),
            ]);
    }



A friend told me @Ragy Edward how to fix this, I have created 6 widgets for each single stats overview and gave each one columnspan = 1; but he told me to do it like in the photo. I must put each 3 widgets or each row in the same stats overview widget and give it columnspan = 'full';
let me share my code with you
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Widgets;

use Filament\Widgets\StatsOverviewWidget as BaseWidget;
use Filament\Widgets\StatsOverviewWidget\Stat;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\PlaceOrder;
use Filament\Widgets\Concerns\InteractsWithPageFilters;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class OrderDeliveredWidget extends BaseWidget
{
    use InteractsWithPageFilters;

    protected int | string | array $columnSpan = 'full';

    protected function getStats(): array
    {
        $statuses = [
            ['model' => Order::class, 'status' => 'to_customer', 'label' => 'On Delivery Orders'],
            ['model' => Order::class, 'status' => 'delivered', 'label' => 'Delivered Orders'],
            ['model' => PlaceOrder::class, 'status' => 'pending', 'label' => 'Pending Orders'],
        ];

        $stats = [];

        foreach ($statuses as $statusInfo) {
            $query = $statusInfo['model']::query();
            
            if ($this->filters['Date']) {
                $query->where('created_at', '>=', $this->getFilterDate($this->filters['Date']));
            }

            $currentCount = $query->where('status', $statusInfo['status'])->count();
            
            $previousPeriodStart = $this->getPreviousPeriodStart($this->filters['Date']);
            $previousCount = $statusInfo['model']::where('status', $statusInfo['status'])
                ->where('created_at', '>=', $previousPeriodStart)
                ->where('created_at', '<', $this->getFilterDate($this->filters['Date']))
                ->count();

            $percentageChange = $this->calculatePercentageChange($previousCount, $currentCount);
            $description = $this->getDescription($percentageChange);
            $icon = $this->getDescriptionIcon($percentageChange);
            $color = $this->getColor($percentageChange);

            $stats[] = Stat::make($statusInfo['label'], $currentCount)
                ->description($description)
                ->descriptionIcon($icon)
                ->color($color);
        }

        return $stats;
    }

    private function getFilterDate(?string $filter): Carbon
    {
        return match($filter) {
            'today' => now()->startOfDay(),
            'week' => now()->startOfWeek(),
            'month' => now()->startOfMonth(),
            'year' => now()->startOfYear(),
            default => Carbon::createFromTimestamp(0),
        };
    }

    protected function getFilters(): ?array
    {
        return [
            'today' => 'Today',
            'week' => 'This week',
            'month' => 'This month',
            'year' => 'This year',
        ];
    }

    private function calculatePercentageChange($oldValue, $newValue): float
    {
        if ($oldValue == 0) {
            return $newValue > 0 ? 100 : 0;
        }
        return (($newValue - $oldValue) / $oldValue) * 100;
    }

    private function getDescription(float $percentageChange): string
    {
        $formattedChange = number_format(abs($percentageChange), 1);
        $direction = $percentageChange >= 0 ? 'increase' : 'decrease';
        return "{$formattedChange}% {$direction}";
    }

    private function getDescriptionIcon(float $percentageChange): string
    {
        return $percentageChange >= 0 
            ? 'heroicon-m-arrow-trending-up'
            : 'heroicon-m-arrow-trending-down';
    }

    private function getColor(float $percentageChange): string
    {
        if ($percentageChange > 10) {
            return 'success';
        } elseif ($percentageChange < -10) {
            return 'danger';
        } else {
            return 'warning';
        }
    }

    private function getPreviousPeriodStart(?string $filter): Carbon
    {
        return match($filter) {
            'today' => now()->subDay()->startOfDay(),
            'week' => now()->subWeek()->startOfWeek(),
            'month' => now()->subMonth()->startOfMonth(),
            'year' => now()->subYear()->startOfYear(),
            default => Carbon::createFromTimestamp(0),
        };
    }
}

